# Convert a Compiled C Program to shellcode (Hex)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, shellcode

So I wanted to convert a compiled C program into Hex format so that I can inject it inside the memory. The problem I am currently facing is that I have no idea how to convert a compiled C file to hex. Can someone show me how it's done?

My C Code (temp.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
printf("Working!");
}
```

Compiled it using gcc:
`gcc -g temp.c -o temp -m32`

Comment: You can use the `objcopy` utility for that.  But keep in mind that just injecting a C program into memory won't be particularly useful for shellcode purposes.  Shellcode usually needs to be specifically written to the requirements of the environment to be useful.  A C compiler is not able to do this.  You'll have to write it in assembly and learn how to do that.

Comment: You won't know where `printf` is in the virtual address space of the target process, in either absolute address or relative distance, so there's no practical way to call it.  You'll need to inline system calls.  Similarly, any data in memory you want to use (like `"Working!"`) will need to be contiguous with your code or constructed on the stack, not in `.rodata`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in assembly using [`write();`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall and `exit();` syscall.

Here code I wrote, file `w.asm` :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

    push    byte  0x0a    
    push    dword "ing!"
    push    dword "Work"
    inc     ebx
    mov     ecx, esp
    mov     dl, 9
    mov     al, 4
    int     0x80

    xor     ebx, ebx
    mov     al, 1
    int     0x80
```

Assembling and linking using `nasm` and `ld` :

```
nasm -f elf w.asm && ld -o w w.o
```

Dump binary file into hex (shellcode style) using objdump one-liner like this:

```
objdump -d ./w | grep '[0-9a-f]:'|grep -v 'file'|cut -f2 -d:|cut -f1-6 -d' '|tr -s ' '|tr '\t' ' '|sed 's/ $//g'|sed 's/ /\\x/g'|paste -d '' -s |sed 's/^/"/'|sed 's/$/"/g'
```

You will get the result like this :

```
"\x6a\x0a\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x21\x68\x57\x6f\x72\x6b\x43\x89\xe1\xb2\x09\xb0\x04\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\xb0\x01\xcd\x80"
```

Comment: Your shellcode wouldn't quite work as real shellcode, only in `_start`: you depend on the upper bytes of EAX being zero, and on EBX being exactly zero.  This is true on Linux process startup (thus at `_start` in a static executable), but won't be true if you injected this code into a buffer overflow.  One way is `xor ebx,ebx` / `lea eax, [ebx+4]` / `lea edx, [ebx+9]` / `inc ebx`.  (EDX is ok to have too high, if you don't mind writing garbage after your string until the write system call encounters an unmapped page.)

Comment: Also, if you're doing to use NASM, you could just use BITS 32 and assemble it into a flat binary that you can hexdump.

Comment: Also, this doesn't really answer the question.  I think techniques for turning asm into shellcode are fairly well known (although if not, this could be the answer to a different question).  I think the point of this question is for someone who doesn't know or understand asm to use a compiler instead of writing by hand, which isn't going to work because compilers don't have an option to make shellcode-friendly asm.  Even with inline-asm macros for system calls, compilers will still usually use `.rodata` for strings, and won't avoid `0` bytes.  (Although clang -Oz might happen to.)